# Unable to filter using ContentDocument id in query in trigger query not retrieving any results

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a requirement to make to make a file private and be available to only the user whose role name consists the name of the file for a specific custom object. For this I am trying to retrieve from Content Document Link with the custom object name LinkedEntity.Type and ContentDocumentid as filters, when I hard code the ContentDocumentid it is working fine but when I try to dynamically provide the ContentDocumentId then the query is not returning any result. I am adding a snippet of my code. Please Help!!. Thanks

```
List<Id> listOfConDocuId = new List<Id>();
for(ContentVersion cv: Trigger.new){
    if((!cv.Title.contains('product proposal')) || (!cv.Title.contains('final')) || (!cv.Title.contains('packet')))
        listOfConDocuId.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
}

Map<Id, Project__c> mapOfProjectId = new Map<Id, Project__c>([SELECT Id FROM Project__c]);

Set<Id> setOfProjectId = mapOfProjectId.keySet();

List<ContentDocumentLink> LinkedProject = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.Title FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId in :setOfProjectId and LinkedEntity.Type='Project__c' and ContentDocumentId IN :listOfConDocuId];`
```

Comment: What kind of trigger is it, before insert? It might be the case that at that point there's no "parent" (ContentDocument). And ContentDocumentLinks come even later in the process (first ...version and ...document has to be created, then you use ...link to connect ...document to your custom object). Run `System.debug(listOfConDocuId);` see if they come out as nulls or something else. If they come out null - you're starting in wrong place and making a trigger on CDL might be better idea. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197848/trigger-on-contentdocumentlink

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction I managed to fix the issue based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to add a WHERE clause for both ID and TYPE. Id should be enough. As far as restricting files to only users with certain roles, have you tried sharing the Custom Object (Project__c) with only those users and then simply linking the files to that Custom Object record with Inferred Permission?

Read more about the sharing types and visibility of Content Document Link here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm